# How to show multiple infowindows using Maps GWT API?

Tags: java, gwt, google-maps-api-2

I wrote the following method:

```
public static void setMarkOnMap(final MapWidget map, String place,
        final String content) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder();
    geocoder.getLatLng(place, new LatLngCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LatLng point) {
            Marker marker = new Marker(point);
            map.addOverlay(marker);
            map.getInfoWindow().open(marker, new InfoWindowContent(content));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure() {}
    });
}
```

And I called it twice, but in the map only one InfoWindow is shown.

Is there any way to show multiple infowindow (from marks) using Google Maps API for GWT?